# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-objec

Tags: php

Hello friends I have a problem I would like to modify an employee but it gives me this error:**Fatal error: Call to a member function setcin() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Application\employe\update.php on line 6**I do not understand why.
This is my function:

```
 public function update(employe $employe){
$this->makes();
$this->st=$this->pdo->prepare("update employe set cin=:cin,nom_em=:nom_em,id_grade=:id_grade,id_affectation=:id_affectation,adress=:adress where id_em=:id_em");
$this->st->bindvalue(':cin',$employe->getcin(),pdo::PARAM_STR);
$this->st->bindvalue(':nom_em',$employe->getnom_em(),pdo::PARAM_STR);
$this->st->bindvalue(':id_grade',$employe->getid_grade(),pdo::PARAM_INT );
$this->st->bindvalue(':id_affectation',$employe->getid_affectation(),pdo::PARAM_INT );
$this->st->bindvalue(':adress',$employe->getadress(),pdo::PARAM_STR);
$exe=$this->st->execute();

}
public function read($id_em){
$this->makes();
$this->st=$this->pdo->prepare("select * from employe where id_em=:id_em");
$this->st->bindvalue(':id_em',$id_em,pdo::PARAM_INT );
$exe=$this->st->execute();
}
```

And here is the call of the function:

```
<?php

include'manager.php';
$manager=new manager();
$co=$manager->read($_POST["id_em"]);
$co->setcin($_POST['cin']);
$co->setnom_em($_POST['nom_em']);
$co->setid_grade($_POST['id_grade']);
$co->setid_affectation($_POST['id_affectation']);
$co->setadress($_POST['adress']);
$manager->update($co);
?>
```

and thank you

Comment: You should check the return values of your function calls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983